# Circuit failing to increment

Tags: vhdl, increment

I'm trying to create a 3 digit 4-bit Binary coded incrementor circuit. The circuit is meant to increment the BCD after every rising clock edge however, it increments but then returns to zero after clock edge. I want the code to increment from count1 and once count1 reaches 9 and count2 to be increment and then the same for count3. I wasn't able to attach the simulation but I can give you the testbench code to save your time if your willing to help thanks.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;


entity bit12_BCD_incrementor is
    Port ( 
       clk  :  in STD_LOGIC ;
       reset:  in STD_LOGIC ;
       inc  :  in STD_LOGIC ;
       out1 :  out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
       out2 :  out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
       out3 :  out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0)
       );
end bit12_BCD_incrementor;

architecture BCD_arch of bit12_BCD_incrementor is

signal count1 , c1next : unsigned(3 downto 0) ;
signal count2 , c2next : unsigned(3 downto 0) ;
signal count3 , c3next : unsigned(3 downto 0) ;
signal fb ,fzero, zero : std_logic;

begin
out1 <= std_logic_vector (count1);
out2 <= std_logic_vector (count2);
out3 <= std_logic_vector (count3);

process(clk, reset, inc)
begin

count1 <= ( others => '0');
count2 <= ( others => '0');
count3 <= ( others => '0');



if (reset = '1') then
   count1 <= ( others => '0')  ;
   count2 <= ( others => '0') ;
   count3 <= ( others => '0') ;


elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then 
  if (inc = '1') then
   count1 <= count1 + 1;

elsif (count1 = 9)    then
 if (inc = '1') then
  count1 <= ( others => '0' ) ;
  count2 <= count2 + 1 ;


elsif (count1 = 9)then 
 if (count2 = 9) then
 count3 <= count3 + 1;






end if;
end if;
end if;
end if;



end process;
```

Comment: It never reaches the Elsif because when inc is high it will always take the if branch

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DskGp.jpg) should work (not verified without a testbench). Note the assumption reset is asynchronous and only signals evaluated in conditions are found in the sensitivity list. The out signals are assigned in concurrent statements so simulation and synthesized hardware provide the same results, simulation otherwise waiting on sensitivity list signal events before updating out1 - out 3.

Answer (score 0):

Your `process` was wrong. You don´t reset the counter to zero after you reach your limit and also you write your counter at two different places in your code!

```
process(clk, reset, inc)
begin

count1 <= ( others => '0');
...
```

and

```
elsif(rising_edge(clk)) then 
   if(inc = '1') then
      count1 <= count1 + 1;
```

So your `count` variables are set to 0 during each cycle of the process. Clean up the `if` statements of your `process`, add the reset conditions for your counter and your solution works:

```
entity DigitCounter is
    Port ( Clk          : in STD_LOGIC;
           Reset        : in STD_LOGIC;
           Direction    : in STD_LOGIC;
           Out1         : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
           Out2         : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
           Out3         : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0)
           );
end DigitCounter;

architecture DigitCounter_Arch of DigitCounter is

    signal Counter1         : INTEGER := 0;
    signal Counter2         : INTEGER := 0;
    signal Counter3         : INTEGER := 0;

    signal CountDirection   : INTEGER := 0;
    signal Limit            : INTEGER := 0;
    signal ResetValue       : INTEGER := 0;

begin

    CountDirection <= 1 when (Direction = '1') else -1;
    Limit <= 9 when (Direction = '1') else 0;
    ResetValue <= 0 when (Direction = '1') else 9;

    process(Clk, Reset, ResetValue)
    begin
        if(Reset = '1') then
           Counter1 <= ResetValue;
           Counter2 <= ResetValue;
           Counter3 <= ResetValue;
        elsif(rising_edge(Clk)) then
            Counter1 <= Counter1 + CountDirection;

            if(Counter1 = Limit) then
                Counter1 <= ResetValue;
                Counter2 <= Counter2 + CountDirection;

                if(Counter2 = Limit) then
                    Counter2 <= ResetValue;
                    Counter3 <= Counter3 + CountDirection;

                    if(Counter3 = Limit) then
                        Counter3 <= ResetValue;
                    end if;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    Out1 <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(Counter1, Out1'length));
    Out2 <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(Counter2, Out2'length));
    Out3 <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(Counter3, Out3'length));

end DigitCounter_Arch;
```

With the following testbench

```
entity Top_TB is
--  Port ( );
end Top_TB;

architecture Behavioral of Top_TB is

    constant ClockPeriod : TIME := 200 ns;

    signal Clock : STD_LOGIC := '0';
    signal Reset : STD_LOGIC := '1';

    signal Out1 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal Out2 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0) := (others => '0');
    signal Out3 : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0) := (others => '0');

    component Top is
        Port ( Clk : in STD_LOGIC;
               Reset : in STD_LOGIC;
               Inc : in STD_LOGIC;
               Out1 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
               Out2 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0);
               Out3 : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 downto 0));
    end component;

begin

    -- Clock generation
    process begin
        wait for (ClockPeriod / 2);
        Clock <= '1';
        wait for (ClockPeriod / 2);
        Clock <= '0';
    end process;

    UUT : component Top port map (  Clk => Clock,
                                    Reset => Reset,
                                    Inc => '1',
                                    Out1 => Out1,
                                    Out2 => Out2,
                                    Out3 => Out3
                                    );

    -- Stimulus
    process begin
        wait for 10 ns;
        Reset <= '0';
    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

you will get this output

[image]